# Contacts created from Messenger app Add a Contact popup is not appearing in Mesibo console

Tags: mesibo

I'm trying to create some contacts from messenger by clicking on Add Contact icon which opens up the popup to make entries.

After entering name & phone number then click on Add button it started showing up in messenger, But the same contact is not appearing in Mesibo console .
Can you please help why there is no entry over there ?

And these entries will be fetched always irrespective of the login success or failed of messenger.

Note : Only by API or directly create from console I could see the contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like browser level indexbased DB is creating and all the users are pushing and fetching from browser level DB only.

[image]